# A simple way to create the appearance of wooden roof shingles?

Tags: material-selection, model-building

I am planning to make a miniature that is approximately 6x5", with a roof covered in wooden shingles. The body of the model will be PU foam.

Are there any suggestions for materials or techniques that I could use to make the roof that do not involve cutting out individual shingles, which would be extremely time consuming.

Comment: A miniature of what, exactly? Can you give the scale? If it's a conventional one, you can try looking for textured sheets they often have at hobby/model making stores (e.g. [this](https://www.noch.com/3d-structured-sheet-roof-tiles/60355/)).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to make miniature shingles I know of is this:

1. Take a thin piece of cardboard. The usual thickness of cereal boxes is best.
2. Cut a strip of this cardboard as wide a single row of shingles + 1/3 extra width.
3. Put vertical cuts into the strip at regular intervals, cutting about 2/3 of the width. It will look more natural if the cuts aren't perfectly perpendicular or spaced.
4. Glue the strips of shingles onto the roof, overlapping each row by 1/3.

If you want to give your shingles a more random or weathered appearance, here are some extra steps to consider:

- Place all your prepared strips of cardboard into a container with a handful of pebbles or small stones and shake it for a while. That introduces random bends and dents and damage to make it look more weathered.
- Take each strip and slightly bend each odd shingle up and each even one down. Then take your scissors and cut a thin sliver from the entire upper row of shingles and bend them back straight. That gives it a very natural and hand-made look. *I saw this trick in a YouTube video but I don't remember who created the video.*
- Cut random corners of individual shingles, cut some shingles in half or cut some away completely. This gives it a very old and damaged look.